# png image being cut off in header

Tags: html, css, png

Using a png image for our logo inside the header of our site. The issue I am having is that the text in the logo (which is in the middle of the logo) is being cut off. So right under the word "Resolutions" the second line of text is not completely showing.

Site is located at and logo is in the top left. Any ideas or suggestions on how to resolve this is appreciated.

```css
#eut-main-header,
.eut-logo {
  height: 125px;
}

.eut-logo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.eut-position-left {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Right click and click inspect. You will see you `height: 125px;` is chopping the image

Comment: It's not the image thats being chopped, it's the second line of text in the middle of the logo where the top of the letters are being cut off. The entire logo shows just not the top of the letters in "therapeutic services"

Comment: In chrome your logo is chopped halfway through the letters. Change the height of the container fixes it

Comment: Could you include your screenshot

Comment: just added screen shot to the original post. This was taken from Chrome. Safari is the same.

Comment: Don't resize the logo if you do not like the result

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the image size and how anti-alaising works. You can fix this by changing the size of the original image to match the actual element (which is 169.22 x 110), or you can change the size of the container element until the problem is resolved.

For the second solution, changing

`.eut-logo a {...}` from `height: 110px;` to `height: 122px` works.

Comment: Tried this but still having the same issue. For clarity, it's the second line of text in the middle of the logo where the top of the letters are being cut off. The entire logo shows just not the top of the letters in "therapeutic services" which is the second line of text in the logo.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong somewhere. The image is natively 300x195, but you're displaying it as 203 x 132 (as of right now). Hence the anti-alias. You need to make them match (for solution one).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is the css properties you are using for logo section. You should remove the height or use the value auto for this line.

You should remove the height, or increase to your need or use auto for value.

```
#eut-main-header, .eut-logo {
height: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Tried this but still having the same issue. For clarity, it's the second line of text in the middle of the logo where the top of the letters are being cut off. The entire logo shows just not the top of the letters in "therapeutic services" which is the second line of text in the logo.